# .Net Filter BindingSource

Tags: .net, filter, bindingsource

If I filter a BindingSource's column like this: `"column1 LIKE '%John%'"`, then all rows containing John on that column will return.

How to return all rows for which column1 contains `[some text]John[some text]Doe` ?

`"column1 LIKE '%John%Doe'"` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

> Wildcard Characters Both the * and %
>   can be used interchangeably for
>   wildcard characters in a LIKE
>   comparison. If the string in a LIKE
>   clause contains a * or %, those
>   characters should be enclosed in
>   brackets ([]). If a bracket is in the
>   clause, each bracket character should
>   be enclosed in brackets (for example
>   [[] or []]). A wildcard is allowed at
>   the start and end of a pattern, or at
>   the end of a pattern, or at the start
>   of a pattern. For example:
>
> "ItemName LIKE '*product*'"
>
> "ItemName LIKE '*product'"
>
> "ItemName LIKE 'product*'"
>
> Wildcard characters are not allowed in
>   the middle of a string. For example,
>   'te*xt' is not allowed.

Therefore, you can't use LIKE to do what you want.  Your next best bet is to get the string representation and use a Regex to parse it looking for the text you want.  That's going to be SLOW.

You COULD do

```
column1 LIKE '%John%' AND LIKE %Doe%'
```

but the logic is different and may not be what you really want.

**Edit - added**

You might be better off doing the filtering at the server level, as your DB might support a wildcard in the middle of the string.  I just tried it on our SQL Server and it works fine. (SQL Server 2005)

Comment: I could eventually split the expression by wilcards and generate X LIKE expressions, where X is the amount of wildcards. Isn't this better ?

Comment: It could be, but it doesn't guarantee the order.  For example, the suggestion I showed above would return rows with "Doe sadasd John" as well as "John asdasdasd Doe"  You'd have the same issue with multiple LIKE statements.  I believe that you may be better off doing the filter on the database query, since the DB may support the wildcard in the middle of the string.  I'm fairly sure SQL Server does at any rate.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   "ItemName LIKE '*john*' and  ItemName LIKE '*doe*'"
```