# BindingSource.Filter any character wildcard

Tags: c#, wildcard, bindingsource

I wanna filter my BindingSource with a column that equals to "ABC_EFG". The underscore can be replaced with just one character, Just like T-SQL syntax. How can I do that?
I tried these and got no result:

```
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 = ABC_EFG";
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 = 'ABC_EFG'";
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 = ABC#EFG";
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 = 'ABC#EFG'";
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 LIKE ABC_EFG"; 
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 LIKE 'ABC_EFG'"; 
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 LIKE ABC#EFG";  
bindingSource1.Filter="col1 LIKE 'ABC#EFG'";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717923/net-filter-bindingsource

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx "A wildcard is allowed at the **start** and **end** of a pattern, or at the end of a pattern, or at the start of a pattern", while you are trying to put wild card in the *middle*

Comment: but in T-SQL there is such wildcard ("_") to be at middle of string. Dont we have it in C# ?